# Can't bind inside ng-show that is in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

So I am working on a small login form using AngularJS and it seemed extremely natural to remove duplicated code by using an ng-repeat directive. Everything is very natural and works well except any kind of binding inside ng-show, this is where things gets unintuitive and break down. A fiddle of the work so far can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K2FuB/4/).

What I am wondering is why does everything break down for ng-show? If I dump the ng-repeat and duplicate the code everything works fine for all three ng-show instances assuming that I manually type the references to the elements and values.

Below is a copy of the fiddle html and javascript:

```
<div ng-app='loginApp' ng-controller='loginController'>
    <form name='loginForm' novalidate>
        <div class='form-group' ng-repeat='field in fields'>
            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
            <input type='{{field.inputType}}' class='form-control' name='{{field.inputName}}' ng-minlength='{{field.minlength}}' ng-maxlength='{{field.maxlength}}' ng-model='field.value' ng-focus='inputFocused'/>
            <!-- The ng-show below doesn't work as expected -->
            <div ng-show="canShowUserMsgs(inputFocused, loginForm.{{field.inputName}}.$dirty, loginForm.{{field.inputName}}.$invalid)">
                <!-- The ng-show below doesn't work as expected -->
                <p ng-show="loginForm.{{field.inputName}}.$error.minlength" class='help-block'>Must be more than {{field.minlength}} characters long.</p>
                <!-- The ng-show below doesn't work as expected -->
                <p ng-show="loginForm.{{field.inputName}}.$error.maxlength" class='help-block'>Must be less than {{field.maxlength}} characters long.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp', []);

loginApp.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.fields = [
        {
            label : "User Name",
            inputType : "text",
            inputName : "userName",
            value : "",
            minlength : 5,
            maxlength : 15
        },
        {
            label : "Password",
            inputType : "password",
            inputName : "password",
            value : "",
            minlength : 5,
            maxlength : 15
        }
        ];

    $scope.canShowUserMsgs = function(inputFocused, inputDirty, inputInvalid) {
        return (inputDirty && inputInvalid && !inputFocused); };
});

loginApp.directive('ngFocus', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      var modelName = attrs['ngFocus'];
      scope[modelName] = false;

      element.bind('focus', function(evt) {
        scope.$apply(function() {scope[modelName] = true;});
      }).bind('blur', function(evt) {
        scope.$apply(function() {scope[modelName] = false;});
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `ng-form` inside the `ng-repeat` and need to do some modifications to how you use the ng-show. Check the working sample of your code.

[working copy](http://jsfiddle.net/seminda/K2FuB/5/)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work: `<p ng-show="loginForm.{{field.inputName}}.$error.minlength"` because the interpretation of the curly brace expression only happens once, there's not two passes: one to generate the bind path without any curly braces, then a second to evaluate the bind path against the scope. It's not like that. Everything happens in a single pass. So, convert it to a controller function call:

```
<p ng-show="minLength(field)"
```